# Can Piqi RPC be used to serve OCaml functions?

Tags: ocaml, protocol-buffers

Piqi-RPC is a service for erlang. This is confusing, because if you look in the sources [here](https://github.com/alavrik/piqi/blob/master/src/piqi_rpc.ml), you can see that some of that rpc is written in OCaml. The documentation for piqi makes it seem like the services expose Erlang functions.

My question is all in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piqi author here. Piqi-RPC is not available for OCaml at the moment, but we'll get there eventually.

`piqi_rpc.ml` is used to export some piqi functionality over pipe. There is no stub generator for this yet. For this limited use case, I just call `gen_*` and `parse_*` functions manually in [piqi_server.ml](https://github.com/alavrik/piqi/blob/master/src/server.ml#L144). My plan is to add RPC stub generator to `piqic-ocaml` and to change `piqi_rpc.ml` to use a new improved and cleaned up RPC protocol version.

Comment: Hey, I'm working on a RPC server myself since I was pretty sure that there wasn't RPC for ocaml. If I share it, would you want to fuse it in with piqi? It uses zmq and serializes using your gen and parse functions over strings, so it should work just fine. Users will just define their designated call backs and a map of function ids to the call backs, and be reaponsible for using the correct id to select function. What do you think?

Comment: I see Piqi-RPC as being transport independent. It will be providing function mapping, serialization/deserialization and standard binary framing format. By default, only pipes will be supported. Perhaps it would be best to maintain support for other transports such as ZMQ as separate projects. Overall, transport support can be done as a very thin layer over the main project. Send me an email if you are interested and we can discuss it further.

Comment: Can we work together to define the requirements of function mapping, serialization, and transport mechanism modularization? I sent you an email.

Comment: Replied. Some details for those who are interested in the subject: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/piqi/SR7Dd7yqC8E/jXB8aY3K2NsJ